# Web API 2 hosted in IIS 7.5 and Windows server 2008 R2 giving 403.14

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api2

There are many other questions similar to this in SO, i am still posting here because none of them are working out for my environment.

The exact error i am getting is,

***HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.***

Enabling Directory browsing in IIS doesn't help at all.

Also tried adding adding all verbs in ExtensionLessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 in IIS Handler mappings.

And also tried removing module WebDAVModule and WebDAV handler in config as shown below.

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
   </modules>
   <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Looks like this is known issue, there is no proper solution to this. Installing IIS 8 is only clean solution as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is still facing this issue, I got it resolved by adding the lines below in my config file:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well. Tried to deploy a Web API 2 app on a WIndows Server 2008R2 machine with IIS 7.5