# web api hosting on iis 7.5 of windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, web-hosting

I have created MVC web api 2.0 and host that on my local machine's iis and it is working very well. Now I am trying to Host that on iis of windows server 2008(Test server).
On windows server 2008 I am getting index of directory of physical path but not the home page of that web application which I was getting on my local machine.

If I write api path on browser it displays - 404 error page.

If I diable directory browsing then it gives 403.14 error

Configuration of win Server 2008

- IIS Installed
- MVC 3 installed
- Directory Browsing Enabled
- Application pool - integrated - .net framework v4.0.30319

web.config

```
     <system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>

 <modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
  <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

No then I was getting Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -2146232576. and I removed some of unused packages and it works.

Comment: targetFramework="4.5.2"....install that framework version and check that your app pool points to that one.

Comment: thanks @Hackerman I have checked and it's already installed.

Comment: And, did you check the app pool for the application?

Comment: Another question, how are you publishing the application?

Comment: yes that app pool working on the same .net version as it was on local machine. to publish application on windows server I am just right click and browse.

Comment: No, I mean, from Visual Studio, are you publishing to folder, to zip app or via ftp?...or you are just copying the folder?...from Visual Studio, right click on your web api project and click on `Publish`

Comment: yes right click on project from visual studio and Publish

Comment: Probably a fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306788/web-api-2-hosted-in-iis-7-5-and-windows-server-2008-r2-giving-403-14

Comment: That fix the problem - thanks man

Comment: You are welcome!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API 2 hosted in IIS 7.5 and Windows server 2008 R2 giving 403.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306788/web-api-2-hosted-in-iis-7-5-and-windows-server-2008-r2-giving-403-14)

Comment: No then I was getting Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -2146232576.
and I removed some of unused packages and it works.